# iOS SwiftUI - How to stick a label to a rotating view without the label rotating too?

Tags: ios, swiftui, rotation

**This is the desired outcome**

[image]

**This is what I have now**

[image]

**Can anyone help? I'm new to SwiftUI and I've been struggling for two days**

The thin line and the rotation works well, but how can I keep the label horizontal at any rotation?

I have tried using a VSTack and that causes undesired behavior. And when I set the rotation only to the rectangle (thin line) I can't figure out how to correctly postion the label dynamically.

**This is my code so far, and the piece at TodayLabel is where this is done**

```
struct SingleRingProgressView: View {
    let startAngle: Double = 270
    let progress: Float // 0 - 1
    let ringWidth: CGFloat
    let size: CGFloat
    let trackColor: Color
    let ringColor: Color
    let centerText: AttributedText?
    let centerTextSubtitle: AttributedText?
    let todayLabel: CircleGraph.Label?

    private let maxProgress: Float = 2 // allows the ring show a progress up to 200%
    private let shadowOffsetMultiplier: CGFloat = 4

    private var absolutePercentageAngle: Float {
        percentToAngle(percent: (progress * 100), startAngle: 0)
    }

    private var relativePercentageAngle: Float {
        // Take into account the startAngle
        absolutePercentageAngle + Float(startAngle)
    }

    @State var position: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) = (x: 0, y: 0)

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(lineWidth: ringWidth)
                            .foregroundColor(trackColor)
                            .frame(width: size, height: size)
                        Circle()
                            .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(min(progress, maxProgress)))
                            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: ringWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                            .foregroundColor(ringColor)
                            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: startAngle))
                            .frame(width: size, height: size)
                        if shouldShowShadow(frame: proxy.size) {
                            Circle()
                                .fill(ringColor)
                                .frame(width: ringWidth, height: ringWidth, alignment: .center)
                                .offset(y: -(size/2))
                                .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(360 * Double(progress)))
                                .shadow(
                                    color: Color.white,
                                    radius: 2,
                                    x: endCircleShadowOffset().0,
                                    y: endCircleShadowOffset().1)
                                .shadow(
                                    color: Color.black.opacity(0.5),
                                    radius: 1,
                                    x: endCircleShadowOffset().0,
                                    y: endCircleShadowOffset().1)

                        }
                        // Today label
                        if let todayLabel = self.todayLabel {
                            ZStack {
                                StyledText(todayLabel.label)
                                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 2, leading: 4, bottom: 2, trailing: 4))
                                    .background(Color.color(token: .hint))
                                    .cornerRadius(2)
                                    .offset(y: -(size/1.5))
                                Rectangle()
                                    .frame(width: 2, height: ringWidth + 2, alignment: .center)
                                    .offset(y: -(size/2))
                            }.rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(Double(todayLabel.degrees)))
                        }
                        VStack(spacing: 4) {
                            if let text = centerText {
                                StyledText(text)
                            }
                            if let subtitle = centerTextSubtitle {
                                StyledText(subtitle)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: 120)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }

    private func percentToAngle(percent: Float, startAngle: Float) -> Float {
        (percent / 100 * 360) + startAngle
    }
    
    private func endCircleShadowOffset() -> (CGFloat, CGFloat) {
        let angleForOffset = absolutePercentageAngle + Float(startAngle + 90)
        let angleForOffsetInRadians = angleForOffset.toRadians()
        let relativeXOffset = cos(angleForOffsetInRadians)
        let relativeYOffset = sin(angleForOffsetInRadians)
        let xOffset = CGFloat(relativeXOffset) * shadowOffsetMultiplier
        let yOffset = CGFloat(relativeYOffset) * shadowOffsetMultiplier
        return (xOffset, yOffset)
    }

    private func shouldShowShadow(frame: CGSize) -> Bool {
        let circleRadius = min(frame.width, frame.height) / 2
        let remainingAngleInRadians = CGFloat((360 - absolutePercentageAngle).toRadians())
        if (progress * 100) >= 100 {
            return true
        } else if circleRadius * remainingAngleInRadians <= ringWidth {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? there are missing components in the code you provided

Comment: @cedricbahirwe that's actually difficult as this code is part of a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile project and the TodayLabel comes from the Common layer which is in Kotlin. But you can remove the if Statement and just comment out the todayLabel and the AttributedText properties. I'll see if I can adjust it something workable.

Comment: The onus on you to create a minimal project that demonstrates the problem you are having. For something like this, it really isn't difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just turn the inner text label back by -angle:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let startAngle: Double = 270
    let progress: Float  = 0.2 // 0 - 1
    let ringWidth: CGFloat = 30
    let size: CGFloat = 200
    let trackColor: Color = .gray
    let ringColor: Color = .blue
    
    let todayLabeldegrees = 120.0
    
    @State var position: (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) = (x: 0, y: 0)
    
    var body: some View {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(lineWidth: ringWidth)
                        .foregroundColor(trackColor)
                        .frame(width: size, height: size)
                    Circle()
                        .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(progress))
                        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: ringWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                        .foregroundColor(ringColor)
                        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: startAngle))
                        .frame(width: size, height: size)
                    
                    // Today label
                    ZStack {
                        Text("todayLabel")
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 2, leading: 4, bottom: 2, trailing: 4))
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                            .shadow(radius: 2)
                            .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(-todayLabeldegrees))  // << turn back
                            .offset(y: -(size/1.5))

                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 2, height: ringWidth + 2, alignment: .center)
                            .offset(y: -(size/2))
                    }
                    .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(todayLabeldegrees))
                    
                    VStack(spacing: 4) {
                        Text("Test").font(.title)
                        Text("subtitle")
                            .frame(maxWidth: 120)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I tried it so many times. It was the order of the modifiers. I was setting the offset of the label before rotating it back with the negative value. Thanks again, much appreciated!